# Using Goutte to extract a namespaced attribute value

Tags: php, goutte

I'm trying to check if I can read `<html>` properties of a webpage to get the owner-declared language.

99% of the sites I checked, I found that info written as `<html lang="XX">` or `<html lang="XX-YY">` but in 1 particular site I found it written as `<html xml:lang="XX">`, and this last case is giving me headache.

I tried

```
$scraper_client = new \Goutte\Client();
$scraper_crawler = $scraper_client->request('GET', $link);
$response = $scraper_client->getResponse();

var_dump( $scraper_crawler->filter('html')->extract('xml:lang')) );
var_dump( $scraper_crawler->filter('html')->extract('xml|lang')) );
var_dump( $scraper_crawler->filter('html')->extract('xml::lang')) );
var_dump( $scraper_crawler->filter('html')->extract('@[xml:lang]')) );
```

But none of them seems working. Did anyone already do something similar?
Thank you in advance.
S.

**EDIT**

Just to complete the question, here is a link that contains the `xml:lang` attribute that is causing me problems:

http://www.ilgiornale.it/news/politica/silvio-berlusconi-centrodestra-oggi-pi-forte-passato-1482545.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it's like Goutte cuts off this attributes.

I've only able to get the value with a regular expression:

```
$scraper_client = new \Goutte\Client();
$scraper_crawler = $scraper_client->request('GET', $link);
$response = $scraper_client->getResponse();
if (preg_match('/xml:lang=["\']{1}(.*?)["\']{1}/', $response, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately none of them works. The first one returns an array with the entire page in [0] and null in [1], the two others always return null :)

Comment: Have you tried without the lang namespace? With only the xml attribute.

Comment: Yes, thanks, same result. I know that I had to use xPath filtering while trying to read og:XXX meta-tags, but at the end I figured out how to do that... while with this one I really cannot understand how to do :)

Comment: I've only been able to get the `xml:lang` value using a regular expression. I know it's not what you were asking about but I have not found other way so I prefer to, at least, share this. See my updated answer.